# Swift: List all objects that have the same protocol implemented

Tags: swift

Hello in my project I have 3 objects that receive the same protocol, is there a way to list all the classes having the same protocol to print it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing

```
if let _ = someObject as? SomeProtocol {
   ///
}
```

you can check if this object conforms to `SomeProtocol`.

An array of object can be compactMapped like this

`let objectsThatConform = arrayOfObjects.compactMap { $0 as? SomeProtocol }`